# Enforce Two-Way SSL in Java CXF clients

Tags: java, ssl, cxf, mutual-authentication

Two-Way SSL - or mutual authentication - is typically dictated in HTTPS by the server. For example, [this tutorial](http://docs.wildfly.org/14/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#enable-two-way-ssltls-in-wildfly-for-applications) explains how to set up WildFly application server to require webservice clients to present a certificate during communication.

However, in our case we need to enforce Two-Way SSL on the client side. That means our client is configured with a client certificate so that it can supply the certificate during handshake. If a server we are connecting to does not ask for the certificate, we want to abort communication.

Descriptions of the SSL handshake like the diagram in the section titled "The SSL Protocol" [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Terms) (a bit further down) explain how the first thing happening is selection of a cipher suite:

> "1. Client hello - The client sends the server information including the
>   highest version of SSL it supports and a list of the cipher suites it
>   supports. (TLS 1.0 is indicated as SSL 3.1.) The cipher suite
>   information includes cryptographic algorithms and key sizes."

On Java side (more specifically: CXF in my case) , it's possible to [filter cipher suites](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/tls-configuration.html)(*"cipherSuitesFilter"*) - so I thought it would be possible to limit cipher suites to those requiring mutual authentication. But I don't find any links between cipher suites and two-way SSL. For example, [this page](https://www.jscape.com/blog/cipher-suites) notes:

> authentication algorithm - dictates how server authentication and (if
>   needed) client authentication will be carried out.

I'm starting to think that means the cipher suite only dictates *how* client authentication is done, not *if* client authentication is required.

That leaves me at a dead end. Is there any other way to enforce client authentication on the client side?

Right now the only solution I can think of is finding the right hook method to implement for SSL communication after the handshake has been done, checking if the connection uses client authentication and aborting if it's not. But I'd like to use any kind of common approach for, if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't find a better solution than the one I already mentioned in my question.
As a client, we can only check whether a connection was established using a client certificate. That does not guarantee that the server thoroughly verified the certificate, just that it requested a certificate.

Our implementation is a custom `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory` that extends `createSocket` methods to check whether `javax.net.ssl.SSLSession.getLocalCertificates()` returns something. If not, an exception subclass of `javax.net.ssl.SSLException` is thrown to abort communication.
The socket factory is set via `org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters.setSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory).`